# Nasa World Wind: SelectListener not triggering on map clicks

Tags: java

I'm using java WWsdk.
I am expecting the SelectListener to respond to user clicks on the map when user clicks just the map (i.e. not an icon or placemark,etc..).

It works fine for me when i click on my objects, but it doesn't trigger when i click "empty space". i.e. like water/land.

The docs for SelectListener says

> If no object is under the cursor but the cursor is over terrain, the select event will >identify the terrain as the picked object and will include the corresponding geographic >position

This statement makes it sound like i should get an event whenever i don't click an object,but i don't get this.

Am i supposed to add some other kind of layer to get clicks on map to trigger select events?

I use this which is working for me for actions i need performed on objects that get clicked:

```
this.worldWindowGLCanvas1.addSelectListener(new SelectListener()
    {
        public void selected(SelectEvent event)
        {
             //Never goes here for clicks on map, just clicks
             //on objects i have already created.     
             doStuff();
        }
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a `MouseListener` using `addMouseListener()`:

```
this.worldWindowGLCanvas1.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        doStuff();
    }
    ...
}
```

You may also want to add the listener to the `AWTInputHandler` instead of the `WorldWindowGLCanvas` if you want to prevent World Wind from doing something else with the click. More details [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31415117/disable-globe-movement-on-click-in-world-wind/31417973#31417973).