# Disable globe movement on click in World Wind

Tags: java, swing, worldwind

I am trying to disable movement of the globe on mouse click in World Wind. I expected to be able to do:

```
void disableGlobeDrag(WorldWindowGLCanvas ww) {
    ww.addMouseMotionListener(new MyMouseMotionListener());
}
```

where `MyMouseMotionListener` consumes all of the mouse events. This is not working so instead I have to do:

```
void disableGlobeDrag(WorldWindowGLCanvas ww) {
    for(MouseMotionListener l : ww.getMouseMotionListeners()) {
        if(l.getClass().toString().equals("class gov.nasa.worldwind.awt.AWTInputHandler")) {
            ww.removeMouseMotionListener(l);
        }
    }
}
```

Is it expected that consumed mouse events should still reach the `gov.nasa.worldwind.awt.AWTInputHandler` listener?

**Update:** `WorldWindowGLCanvas` is just calling `addMouseMotionListener()` on `java.awt.Component` so apparently I don't understand how consuming events works.

**Update 2:** despite sharing interfaces with Swing, calling `WorldWindowGLCanvas.removeMouseMotionListener()` with `AWTInputHandler` as the argument will prevent all other `MouseMotionListener`s from receiving events. The add and remove methods on `AWTInputHandler` should be used instead.

Comment: Why would adding another listener prevent any of the existing listeners from receiving events?

Comment: If I consume the event on the most recently added listener, shouldn't that prevent other listeners from receiving notifications of the same event?

Comment: How do you "consume" the event? Looking through java.awt.Component and java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster, I don't see any concept of consuming events. It looks like it just always delivers them to all registered listeners.

Comment: Using `MouseEvent.consume()` - this ended up working but only when the listener was added to World Wind's `AWTInputHandler` rather than using the methods on the `WorldWindowGLCanvas`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately removing the `MouseMotionListener` as @trashgod suggested does not work since there is some World Wind specific behavior happening: removing `gov.nasa.worldwind.awt.AWTInputHandler` causes other `MouseMotionListener`s to stop receiving event notifications.

To disable globe dragging and still receive events in another `MouseMotionListener` the following steps were necessary:

**Get a reference to World Wind's `AWTInputHandler`:**

```
AWTInputHandler wwHandler = null;
// get World Wind's AWTInputHandler class:
for (MouseMotionListener l : ww.getMouseMotionListeners()) {
    if(l instanceof AWTInputHandler) {
        wwHandler = (AWTInputHandler)l;
        break;
    }
}
```

**Create a `MouseMotionListener` which consumes events:**

```
public class MyMouseMotionListener implements MouseMotionListener {
    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
        // consume the event so the globe position does not change
        e.consume();
        if (e.getSource() instanceof WorldWindowGLCanvas) {
            // get the position of the mouse
            final WorldWindowGLCanvas canvas = ((WorldWindowGLCanvas) e.getSource());
            final Position p = canvas.getCurrentPosition();
            // do something with the position here
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
        e.consume();
    }
}
```

**Add the mouse motion listener to the `AWTInputHandler`:**

```
if(wwHandler != null) {
    wwHandler.addMouseMotionListener(new MyMouseMotionListener());
} else {
    // I don't think this should happen unless the AWTInputHandler
    // is explicitly removed by client code
    logger.error("Couldn't find AWTInputHandler");
}
```

That said, I have no idea why `WorldWindowGLCanvas` is using `Component.addMouseMotionListener()` rather than `AWTInputHandler.addMouseMotionListener()`.

Answer (score 2):

**Why it's not working:**

As discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2159803/230513), many event sources maintain an [`EventListenerList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/event/EventListenerList.html). The prescribed scheme allows an arbitrary number of listeners to be added or removed. This related [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8302423/230513) lists all instances of `DocumentListener` registered to text component's `Document`. No one listener preempts another.

**What you might do:**

Given an instance of a [`WorldWindowGLCanvas`](http://builds.worldwind.arc.nasa.gov/worldwind-releases/1.3/docs/api/gov/nasa/worldwind/awt/WorldWindowGLCanvas.html), you might look at the array returned by `getMouseMotionListeners()` and invoke `removeMouseMotionListener()` as warranted.

Answer (score 1):

After struggling with a way to do this and stumbling across this solution, I believe I've come up with the "correct" solution. Removing the mouse motion listener completely does technically work, but it breaks other functionality that might be useful (KML tree node selecton, on screen view controls).

#### Create a subclass an input handler to remove the "move to" functionality

```
public class MyOrbitViewInputHandler extends OrbitViewInputHandler
{
  public MyOrbitViewInputHandler()
  {
    // Disable single click to pan functionality
    ViewInputAttributes.ActionAttributes actionAttrs =
      this.getAttributes().getActionMap(ViewInputAttributes.DEVICE_MOUSE).getActionAttributes(ViewInputAttributes.VIEW_MOVE_TO);
    actionAttrs.setMouseActionListener(null);
  }
}
```

#### Specify your new input handler in your worldwind.xml configuration file

```
<Property name="gov.nasa.worldwind.avkey.ViewInputHandlerClassName"
          value="mil.dtra.nucs.coe.ui.map.MyOrbitViewInputHandler"/>
```

Using this method, all other mouse interactions that take place on the canvas will still work correctly, but the "single click to pan" functionality is removed.

If you're curious about what other behaviors are specified that you could potentially override, you can look at gov.nasa.worldwind.awt.BasicViewInputHandler